# mvc area calling controller from the main project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a main mvc project and an area

The Area uses the shared _Layout.cshtml from the main project. In the shared _Layout.cshtml, there is a RenderPartial("GlobalNavigation","Navigation") that call the controller "Navigation" in the main project. So I got this error

```
The IControllerFactory 'abc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Navigation'.
```

I guess its because the view is calling the Controller "Navigation" in the Area, but the controller "Navigation" is in the main project. How can I fix this?

_Layout.cshtml

```
<div id="global-nav">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("GlobalNavigation", "Navigation"); }
</div>
```

Comment: try setting the area to `""`

Comment: Why have you created an Area if you want to use the Controller in the main project?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div id="global-nav">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("GlobalNavigation", "Navigation", new { area = "" }); }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. what is the "area" in that line means?

Comment: Well, I don't understand your question. "area" is the Area in your MVC project. When you set `area = ""`, you are actually telling the asp.net server to use the controller in the "main project".

Comment: You pass `new { area = "" }` as an object that represents your RouteValues. You can specify the controller and action in a RouteValue as well. Like this: `Html.RenderAction("GlobalNavigation", new { controller = "Navigation", area = "" });`

Comment: You can read about routing here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the controller argument if you're just loading a partial? Is there logic being build in the controller method?

Try just:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GlobalNavigation"); }
```

Other wise, I'd suggest using an HTML helper in your project to build our your main navigation.

eg.

Helper in `PROJECT.Web.ExtensionMethods.HtmlExtensions`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace OHTP.Web.ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString NavMenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, string controlName, string activeClassName)
        {
            if (helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == actionName &&
                helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == controlName)
            {
                var menuLink = helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, new { Controller = controlName }, new {Class = activeClassName}); 
                return menuLink;
            }

            return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controlName);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it in the partial with

```
<%= Html.NavMenuLink("Copy to display", "ControllerName", "Link", "class") %>
```

Comment: thanks. Can you elaborate on what the "Link" and "Class" mean? sorry I am very new to mvc

Comment: Link is the link that the anchor URL will point to, class is active and will add an active class based on where you're at (for styling)